# What's the upcoming Java concurrency library: jsr166y? jsr166z?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-7

I wanted to play around with the upcoming concurrency library which
is going to be included in
Java 7 according to [**this website**](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#jsr166).

It seems to be named **JSR166**.

In most places its reference implementation is referred as **jsr166y**,
while few resources call it **jsr166z**.

I discovered two totally **different** javadocs for each reference implementation.

- Docs for [**jsr166y**](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/)
- Docs for [**jsr166z**](http://www.javac.info/jsr166z/)

Now, which implementation is going to be included in Java 7?

**EDIT**
While people who answered suggest that jsr166y is the thing for Java 7,
I discovered [**this** document (TS-5515)](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/j1sessn.jsp?sessn=TS-5515&yr=2008&track=javase) from JavaOne.
This document refers to Java 7 but mentions LinkedAsyncAction
which is only present in jsr166z javadocs. (Confusion...)

Comment: Note:  The document you refer to also explicitly says to download jsr166y -- on slide 14.

Comment: jsr166y doc link is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSR 166 was the original Java concurrency jsr for Java 5 that created java.util.concurrent.  They did a maintenance rev in Java 6 called JSR 166x.  The Java 7 maintenance rev is JSR 166y.  JSR 166z is the closures prototype version.

Currently slated to be included in JSR 166y is:

- Fork/join (but NOT the ParallelArray framework)
- TransferQueue / LinkedTransferQueue collection
- Phasers (CyclicBarriers on steroids)

Push to JDK 8 (at least):

- Fences API (low level), trying to remove use of Unsafe calls
- ConcurrentReferenceHashMap (variable strong/weak refs, concurrent, etc)

For more info, [javadoc here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/) or join the concurrency-interest mailing list:

- http://cs.oswego.edu/mailman/listinfo/concurrency-interest

Comment: So the downloadable jsr166y JAR is just not yet complete, right?

Comment: Probably not.  I think the jar may only include the ForkJoin stuff.

Comment: FYI doc link for jsr166y is broken.

Comment: What is the license of this jar?? Is it a Oracle BCL or open source license??

Answer (score 3):

The link on the javac.info site (jsr166z) uses BGGA closures which will not be in JDK7.

The link on Doug Lea's site (jsr166y) should be up to date. Doug is the spec lead. The API has been pruned down to the basics as how the fork-join framework will be used in practice is not yet clear. Presumably libraries will be available at a slightly higher level, and when thing settle down more can be added to JDK8.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at various references available (for example, [this Email](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2009-January/005727.html) from Doug Lea), it seems clear that the current JSR for JDK7 concurrency additions is jsr166y.  Additionally, if you go to the web page [Closures for the Java Programming Language (aka BGGA)](http://www.javac.info/) and look at (what is currently) the 4th bulleted item "Doug Lea's jsr166y fork-join framework", jsr166y is described as the fork-join framework "without function types" and jsr166z is described as the fork-join framework "with function types."

It looks like jsr166z is a cross between concurrency additions and BGGA. Perhaps this provides concurrency utilities required by BGGA?

Comment: BGGA does not require these concurrency additions. The design of the extra additions could be influenced by what sort of closures we get beyond anonymous inner classes.